# What is the best way to check if a FileInputStream is closed?

Tags: java, inputstream, fileinputstream, zipinputstream

So I have this *FileInputStream* that is required to create a *ZipInputStream* and I want to know what happens to the *ZipInputStream* if the *FileInputStream* is closed. Consider the following code:

```
public void Foo(File zip) throws ZipException{
     ZipInputStream zis;
     FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(zip);

     try{
         zis = new ZipInputStream(fis);
     } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
         throw new ZipException("Error opening ZIP file for reading", ex);
     } finally {
         if(fis != null){ fis.close(); 
     }
}
```

Does **zis** remais open? What happens to the ZipInputStream object? Is there a way I can test this?

Comment: `zis` remains open.. you have to close it explicitly

Comment: Is there a way to test that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using java 7, the best practice is to use 'try with resources' block.
So resource will be auto closed.

Consider the folowing example:

```
static String readFirstLineFromFile(String path) throws IOException {
    try (BufferedReader br =
               new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
        return br.readLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be the right way using `try with resource` block available from java 7.

In this way the resources (fis and zis) will be closed automatically at end of try block.

```
try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(zip);  
     ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(fis)) 
{
   // Do your job here ...
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
   throw new ZipException("Error opening ZIP file for reading", ex);
}
```

[The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

> The try-with-resources statement is a try statement that declares one
>   or more resources. A resource is an object that must be closed after
>   the program is finished with it. The try-with-resources statement
>   ensures that each resource is closed at the end of the statement.